# How to find a Vector3 that is 0,0,0 in an array

Tags: unity-game-engine

This code is working:

```
/* create empty list */
Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[50];
/* add only one element */
vertices[0] = new Vector3(0, 1, 2);

/* test with non-null vectors */
Vector3 test = new Vector3(4, 5, 6);
Vector3 test2 = new Vector3(0, 1, 2);
Vector3 found = Array.Find(vertices, x => x == test);
if (found != Vector3.zero) {
    Debug.Log("OK");
} else {
    Debug.Log("Not found");
}
Vector3 found2 = Array.Find(vertices, x => x == test2);
if (found2!= Vector3.zero) {
    Debug.Log("OK");
} else {
    Debug.Log("Not found");
}
```

What annoys me is that it *always* returns something, *even when the element is not found*. When the element is not found, it returns `Vector3.zero`.

My question is: what if you want to have a `Vector3.zero` in the array (which is my case actually)? How do you deal with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `Array.Find<T>` is defined to return a `default(T)` when nothing is found. As `T` in this case is a struct, and structs are value types, `default(T)` can not be null, but the default for that struct, which is equal to `Vector3.zero`. So there is no way for you to distinguish between a successfully found `Vector3.zero`, and no match.

`Array.IndexOf(array, value)` will return the index of the first element that is equal to `value`, or `-1` if none is found. That should work just fine for you. If the result is not -1, you can use that result to get the matching element from your array.

Comment: I should not say "thank you in the comments". So... **`Thumbs up!`**! :)